# Why can't a template type be a friend class in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, standards, friend

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    friend class T;
    int n;
};

struct B
{
    B()
    {
        A<B>{}.n; 
        // error : 'n' is a private member of 'A<B>'
    }
};
```

Why can't a template type be a friend class in C++?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the usage of keyword `class`, you're forward declaring a new type named `T`; which doesn't refer to the template parameter `T`. (It shadows the template parameter `T` in fact.)

Just remove the keyword `class`, then the friend declaration won't forward declare a new type.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    friend T;
    int n;
};
```

[This usage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) (`friend` *simple-type-specifier*;  `friend` *typename-specifier*;) was introduced since C++11.